# How to append characters before and after values in a .config file?

Tags: java, properties, config

How to append characters before and after values in a .config file?

My automation framework has the following properties file:

```
browser=chrome
url=https://www.example.com
username=userJoe
```

The following code will generate a .config file from the .properties file listed above:

```
public static void readXmlValues() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    //load from your original file;
    FileInputStream inputProps = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\joe.blogs\\Desktop\\AutoFramework\\src\\main\\java\\BuyAGiftFramework\\config\\config.properties");
    p.load(inputProps);
    //store in xml format
    FileOutputStream outputXml = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\joe.blogs\\Desktop\\AutoFramework\\src\\main\\java\\BuyAGiftFramework\\config\\properties.config");
    p.storeToXML(outputXml, "Properties Example");
}
```

My current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Properties Example</comment>
<entry key="browser">chrome</entry>
<entry key="url">https://www.example.com</entry>
<entry key="username">joeblogs@example.com</entry>
</properties>
```

**Expected Output (Need #{ }# to be added before and after values.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Properties Example</comment>
<entry key="browser">#{chrome}#</entry>
<entry key="url">#{https://www.example.com}#</entry>
<entry key="username">#{joeblogs@example.com}#</entry>
</properties>
```

Comment: Where does the Properties class come from ? It would help to know what sort of methods it exposes.

Comment: @Hassan thanks for your comment, my properties file is listed below I have just created a properties file within my projects directory which contains values and in turn the code above will copy the file and create a .config file as listed above however I need to append #{  }# to each of the values listed within the .config file